# DLL project : migrating from Qt + MinGW to Visual Studio

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator

I'm making a DLL, written in C++ with Qt Creator (but no Qt stuff inside, pure homemade C++), and using a standard qmake + MinGW/g++ build process. My friend is doing the framework/main soft, and he's using Visual Studio Express 2015, and he's supposed to use my DLL inside of that. Because of that I want to use the same visual studio compiler for my project in Qt Creator.

So I noticed that Qt Creator had auto detected the Visual Studio C++ 14 compiler, which I believe is the one attached to Visual Studio Express 2015. When I create a kit with that compiler and set my project to compile with that kit, I get a suggested "Make" step which calls jom in the bin folder of my Qt Creator installation. I have no idea what this is and I get the following output (see below).

I don't know what to do from here. I also tried to create a compiler directly from the nmake executable in my Visual Studio installation, and then using it - but I get a very similar error about '-' not being recognized as an option. Any hints are greatly appreciated !

```
12:56:27: Starting: "C:\Qt\qtcreator-3.1.1\bin\jom.exe" 
Usage: jom @commandfile
       jom [options] [/f makefile] [macro definitions] [targets]

nmake compatible options:
/A build all targets
/D display build information
/E override environment variable macros
/F <filename> use the specified makefile
/G display included makefiles
/H show help
/I ignore all exit codes
/K keep going - build unrelated targets on error
/N dry run - just print commands
/NOLOGO do not print logo
/P print makefile info
/R ignore predefined rules and macros
/S silent mode
/U print content of inline files
/L same as /NOLOGO
/W print the working directory before and after other processing
/X <filename> write stderr to file.
/Y disable batch mode inference rules

jom only options:
/DUMPGRAPH show the generated dependency graph
/DUMPGRAPHDOT dump dependency graph in dot format
/J <n> use up to n processes in parallel
/KEEPTEMPFILES keep all temporary files
/VERSION print version and exit
Error: unknown command line option '-' in arguments: '/L-j4'
12:56:27: The process "C:\Qt\qtcreator-3.1.1\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 128.
Error while building/deploying project Ford_DAT_framework_DLL_as_plugin (kit: MVS Ford)
When executing step 'Make'
12:56:27: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I used qmake -tpvc to generate a VCproj file which compiled almost immediately in Visual Studio Express 2015 which my friend uses. I guess that's a valid solution to my problem then !